# How to set parent-child relation in a hierarchy tree form

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus

I have a `ORACLE` table data where data represents parent-child relation. But in my table there has no such relation. So how can I set parent-child relation in my table where no relation exists.

My table some sample data is given below for understanding.

| ID | CODE | NAME | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0005 | ROOT |  |
| 15 | 0015 | ASSETS |  |
| 25 | 0025 | CASH AND BANK BALANCE |  |
| 35 | 0035 | CASH IN HAND |  |
| 45 | 0045 | CASH IN VAULT |  |
| 55 | 0055 | CASH IN HAND LCY (VAULT) |  |
| 60 | 0060 | CASH IN HAND FCY (VAULT). |  |
| 75 | 0075 | CASH AT ATM |  |
| 85 | 0085 | CASH AT ATM |  |
| 120 | 0120 | BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK |  |
| 130 | 0130 | BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK LCY |  |
| 135 | 0135 | BAL. WITH BANGLADESH FCY |  |

From above table, `ROOT` represents my table's data root. Under its `ASSETS` represent child of `ROOT`. Under the `ASSETS`, `CASH AND BANK BALANCE` is child. Under `CASH AND BANK BALANCE`, `CASH IN HAND` and `BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK` are child. `CASH IN VAULT` and `CASH AT ATM (0075)` are child of `CASH IN HAND`. `CASH IN HAND LCY (VAULT)` and `CASH IN HAND FCY (VAULT).` are child of `CASH IN VAULT`. Similarly for `CASH AT ATM` and `BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK`, `CASH AT ATM (0085)` and `BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK LCY` and `BAL. WITH BANGLADESH FCY` are child respectively.

So from this data how can I make child-parent relational data.

My final data table would be like as following:

| ID | CODE | NAME | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0005 | ROOT |  |
| 15 | 0015 | ASSETS | 5 |
| 25 | 0025 | CASH AND BANK BALANCE | 15 |
| 35 | 0035 | CASH IN HAND | 25 |
| 45 | 0045 | CASH IN VAULT | 35 |
| 55 | 0055 | CASH IN HAND LCY (VAULT) | 45 |
| 60 | 0060 | CASH IN HAND FCY (VAULT). | 45 |
| 75 | 0075 | CASH AT ATM | 35 |
| 85 | 0085 | CASH AT ATM | 75 |
| 120 | 0120 | BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK | 25 |
| 130 | 0130 | BAL WITH BANGLADESH BANK LCY | 120 |
| 135 | 0135 | BAL. WITH BANGLADESH FCY | 120 |

Comment: How large is your table? I mean, how many rows does it have? If not that many, perhaps you'll faster/easier do it manually than write code to do it for you.

Comment: @Littlefoot, my table contains `17518` row.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an obvious method of automating this (as you have duplicate names with different codes); instead, manually specify the parent-child relationships:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT  15 AS id, 5 AS parent_id FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  25,  15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  35,  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  45,  35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  55,  45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  60,  45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  75,  35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  85,  75 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 120,  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 130, 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 135, 120 FROM DUAL
) src
ON (src.id = dst.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET parent_id = src.parent_id;
```

Comment: It's manual way to update value. Cause I've an excel data file, from where I can manually update this. So there have any scope to avoid it not doing merge or update my excel file.

Comment: @SadmanZIhan You need to run the `MERGE` in the database and not in Excel. It will not merge or update your Excel file.

Comment: In my table there are `17518` rows, then I need to write select statement almost `17514` times.

Comment: @SadmanZIhan If you have the data in Excel then get Excel to generate the select statement using string concatenation and then copy-paste it into a `MERGE` statement. We cannot help you with writing it more succinctly if there is no logic that defines how the rows are related other than that in your spreadsheet.